# Generalized Load Balancing (GLB) using Linear Programming (LP)

Tags: java, algorithm, implementation, load-balancing

In one of my project - I have a scenario where I need to implement an algorithm capable of doing load balancing. Now, unlike the general load balancing problem present in CS theory (which is NP hard) - where the task is to allocate M loads in N servers (M >> N), such that the maximum load in any one server is minimized, the case that I am dealing with is a little more generic. In my case, the load balancing problem is more generic in the sense - it has more constraints in the form that - such and such job can only be assigned to such an such server (lets say for example job M_{i} has some special security requirements and hence can be allocated/executed only on secure server N_{j}.

Now I looked at the Kleinberg/Tardos book and I found a section (11.7) on the more generic load balancing problem (load balancing with constraints) and I found that this problem is an exact match for the situation I am in. The Generic Load Balancing problem has been converted from IP to LP taking advantage of the fact that LP can result in fractional assignment of jobs to machines which has later been rounded off adding an additional O(MN) time to the process. This approximation solution has then been shown to be within a factor of 2 times from the minimum possible.

Can someone point me to some C/Java/Python/MATLAB code where this algorithm has been implemented? As KL book hardly gives any examples or sample pseudo/actual code, it is hard to get the algorithm internalized completely sometimes. Also as for the linear programming part of the problem - what kind of an implementation is suitable for it - Simplex/Interior Point? How much difference will it make when complexity from this LP part is added to the problem (to the fractional re-assignment part)? Unfortunately, the KL book is not very thorough in these aspects.

Some sample C/Java/Python/MATLAB code (or pointers to code) showing some real implementation of this complete algorithm would be greatly helpful.

Edit: The original paper is "David B. Shmoys, Éva Tardos: An approximation algorithm for the generalized assignment problem. Math. Program. 62: 461-474 (1993)"

Comment: Have you thought about treating it as a stochastic process? You could compute the expected server to use for the current task. If the task has special security restrictions then can compute the condition expected value. Also if you noticing a server is not performing well, could use Bayes theorem to update the distribution to decrease its probability proportionally.

Comment: Well, I am trying to solve it in a deterministic fashion right now, not going into the randomize route. I have searched exhaustively and I have not even found one single implementation of the above algorithm. Now I am thinking of reading the actual Tardos paper (I think this is her algorithm as she is an authority on Network flows) and then possibly rolling one implementation myself.

Comment: Have a look at some simplex point LP algorithms and just adapt one and add the constraints. That's what I would do.

Comment: Can you post the obj function and constraints here? Or a link to a public URL ?  It seems an interesting question.

Comment: Actually I have used this particular algorithm in one of my recent research papers. The paper is still under peer review. In fact the algorithm that I ended up using is the minimal cost (C) load balancing problem (L). This is also called "bi-criteria" problem that means we must ensure that the objective function f(C;X) is less than C_{total} such that total load assigned to any server is within  some value in the range [0, L] where L = sum_{i} W_{i}, W_{i} is the  size of the individual object.

Comment: The original paper is "David B. Shmoys, Éva Tardos: An approximation algorithm for the generalized assignment problem. Math. Program. 62: 461-474 (1993)". The problem is NP-hard. It has been shown in this paper that if a solution to this problem exists then (for a value of the load inside the range [0,L] say 0<= T <= L) then LP can find it by blowing the load by at most a factor of 2T (hence 2-approx). Also, during implementation I found that as you reduce T further and further say towards T ~ 0.25 * L, the space of feasible solution set starts to decrease very drastically.

Comment: I have used GLPK 4.47 and Java to write code for implementing this algorithm. I can't upload the research manuscript right now! Sorry. But I can upload the code and a small pdf that includes all the LP equations in Google code or something if there is some interest. Thanks.

Comment: GLPK **is** a good start. It's fast and the description language is easy to learn. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

One way in which I did this was to load balance according to the current load on each machine. So if there are three machines A,B,C..... A has a load of 10, B had a load of 5 and C has a load of 2 then the next task (which lets say has a load of 3) should go to C(3+2 = 5 < all other combinations). In case of equality given that the task which starts first usually finishes first(at least most of the times) remove the oldest task from each machine and repeat the above process... Do this recursively